# Activating Windows 8.1 with BIOS product key with batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, wmic

I need to deploy windows images to several computers that came with Windows 8.1.
I did manage to inject drivers and updates and some necessary softwares to the installation image, but somehow it seems that just installing Windows won't activate the operating system, and I have to find the license keys embedded in the BIOS and activate them manually.

I found out that `wmic path softwarelicenseingservice get oa3xoriginalproductkey` could be used to extract the product key from the bios, and I am thinking about composing a batch file that uses this command in joint with `slmgr -ipk` and `slmgr -ato`, and then make it run as the firstlogon command.

The trouble is that I don't know a lot about batch syntax, and I am having a hard time assigning the product key as a variable and passing it over to slmgr commands.

It seems that the wmic command returns the result as:

```
OA3xOriginalProductKey  
XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX      
<blank line>
```

So there it returns the product key in a three line text, with the actual useful information sandwiched between other strings. How can I just get the middle(or second) line from this text and assign it as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you. Note it does involve a temporary text file.

```
wmic path softwarelicenseingservice get oa3xoriginalproductkey > temp.txt
3<temp.txt (
set /p var= <&3
set /p var= <&3
)
del temp.txt
Echo %var%
```

Which will always extract the second line of output from the command.
I have tested this with the data you provided and it outputted `XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`. TO access this variable always refer to it as `%var%`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i would do it

Logon scripts [accept powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753404.aspx) scripts which has much more features and strength in it than the old batch files.

```
$key = Get-WmiObject -Class SoftwareLicensingService | 
Select-Object OA3xOriginalProductKey | foreach { "{0}" -f $_.OA3xOriginalProductKey }
```

with this command, you get your ProductID into the $key variable and free to do any manipulation you'd like with it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Although I will likely use batch this time(I cannot afford to try out something I new right now...), I see that powershells are much more powerful than batch commands. Next time I will try to learn more about this thing and implement to my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
cscript.exe C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /upk

cscript.exe C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /cpky

for /f "tokens=2 delims='='" %%K IN ('wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductkey /value') do set pk=%%K

cscript.exe C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %pk%

cscript.exe C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /ato

cscript.exe C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /dli
```

save this as batch file and try

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed.

It works perfect.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims='='" %%K IN ('wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductkey /value') do set pk=%%K

slmgr.vbs /ipk "%pk%"

slmgr.vbs /ato
```